# Marketing cloud journey wait till event happen

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Please let me know how to do this. In Marketing Cloud Journey, I would like to send an email and then update a field on the Account object. I'm going to select the data source as Salesforce data. Whenever an update occurs on a specific field on the Account object, let's say the Invitation Link field, at the same time, I need to send an email. Then, I want to update the Notes field in the Salesforce Account object with the date of the entry. My doubt is, do I need to add a "Wait Until" event split? If it's asking me to choose an API, in this scenario, there is no API involved. It's just Salesforce data.